# I have to close app and open again for android file upload to work

Tags: java, android, multipartform-data

I have an Android application that records an audio file and uploads it to an API for fingerprinting. The app works well when it uploads for the first time and gets the right response. However, on trying to upload again the request from the app seems to reach the server without the uploaded file. Strangely, when I close the app completely and open it again, it works well. However, I want it to be able to do the uploads continuously without having to close it after every attempt.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   class UploadFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      String responseString = "";
      HttpResponse response = null;
      try {
         //below is the API url
         String url = "http://1**.**.**.**:8000/api/tag/";
         File track = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mezzo.mp3");
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
         MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
         reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

         FileBody fb = new FileBody(track);
         //InputStream inputStream = new ;
         //reqEntity.addPart("track", fb);
         reqEntity.addBinaryBody("track", track);
         final HttpEntity myEntity = reqEntity.build();
         httppost.setEntity(myEntity);
         Log.i("request", String.valueOf(myEntity));
         response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

         //process response
         responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         if (null!=response)
         {
             try
             {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (null != httpEntity)
                {
                   httpEntity.consumeContent();
                }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
     return responseString;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(final String responseString) {
     runOnUiThread(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     });
  }
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to run the task? Also wondering if defining HttpEntity as final is the right thing to do (but not sure)

Comment: are you sure the file is recorded on the 2nd time? as it could be empty or anything else could be wrong regarding the file itself not the http request ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I suspect that the http response might not be consumed entirely.

Can you try consuming the response before you return from the function in a finally block:

```
finally
{
    if (null!=response)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (null != httpEntity)
            {
                httpEntity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity() fails with unknown symbol 'response'. Should this be inside the try block or where should it be.

Comment: You need to declare 'HttpResponse response = null' before the try block to access it in finally. Also, editing the finally block to add a null check.

Comment: And the finally block above goes at the end of the try-catch block you have.

Comment: I updated the code. Still getting the same behavior.